# Trigger with case when

Tags: t-sql

I have simple problem but I do not know what am I doing wrong and how to solve it. I wrote a trigger on table. Can you advice me?

```
alter trigger PriceEU on pojazdyEN
after update,insert
as
begin
declare @value nvarchar(50)
set @value = (select i.Currency from inserted i inner join Cars s on i.ID = s.ID)
case @value 
when 'EURO' then update Cars set PriceEuro =Price
when 'DOLLARS' then update Cars set PriceEuro = (Price*1.2)
else update Cars set PriceEuro = (Price*0.5)

end
```

Comment: "The CASE expression cannot be used to control the flow of execution of Transact-SQL statements, statement blocks, user-defined functions, and stored procedures. For a list of control-of-flow methods, see Control-of-Flow Language (Transact-SQL)." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#remarks

Answer (score 3):

You should make the `CASE` expression the predicate of the update:

```
UPDATE Cars
SET PriceEuro = CASE @Value WHEN 'EURO' THEN Price
                            WHEN 'DOLLARS' THEN Price*1.2
                            ELSE Price*0.5 END
```